# How to convert a capturing group to a non-capturing group in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace all urls in the text with hyperlink using regular expression. The urls must start with either `http://` or `https://`. And they must contain some TLD, e.g. `.com`, `.org`, or `.co.uk` etc.

Below is my `regex` pattern in `PHP`:

`$pattern = "/(http)+(s)?:\/\/(\S)+(\.){1}/i";`

So if you use the following code:

```
$str = "this http://dd is a String http://www.example.com and this a String https://anotherexample.co.uk";

echo preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>", $str);
```

It gives me following output:

[image]

You can see that the TLD part is not included in the hyperlink. So how can I convert capturing group `(\.){1}` to non-capturing group to also cover TLD?

Comment: What about links like `http://www.example.com/abc` or `https://test.net/a/?b=c&d=e#f` you only want to replace domains?

Comment: @bobblebubble can they also be replaced with the their corresponding hyperlinks?

Comment: Maybe something like [`https?:\/\/([^\s.,!]+\.[^\s,!]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nUj5uA/1) see [this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##fZFBT8MwDIXv@xWmTHQTVQLXbd2uHCdxXEflpd5aNU2ixFWZEL99ZIOBOEBOTt7zFz/Z1e50WqzWT@vRaBzYQw4J102AmtnNpKwqiBeEZ/aNOVxfh2EQ9Iqd0ySU7QBNBZeuX8YQnWgs1@R/zKJvhRCFScQIPk@iG9MG0E1Lf/Al7hRY/w1lCiwMsUS52uXqrsrpdg9H24M1@ggDGga24MlpVASV7bAxYZXMY0aHzORNzJnKC281K2QhJ5uXIojsZntfiHN5rqaySWMLqdqC83Qov4ClQq13qNrJlZbBvjeKG2sm424KbzHauItfoPd4LDt0k7TmTgdHqkGtavQhzf4Ry4qUrSjNIm06jzRP3Meh0wVC7WmfJ6kYd5uHrUgTYPQH4jwpdxpNmywv0mOUFhKXMcB7BufNRs7p9AE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

`https?:\/\/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+[.a-z]* /i`

1. Keep the 's' in 'https' optional using `?`
2. Use `[a-z]+` to capture the first set of letters after 'https'
3. Ensure there is at least one '.' followed by one or more letters
4. The rest of the slug is optional and can appear zero or more times `[.a-z]*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EIL1WI/1)

Comment: I modified your suggested pattern to `/https?:\/\/[a-z]+\.[a-z0-9-]+[.a-z]*/i` to cover numbers and hyphens in the domain name, e.g. `w3schools.com` or `my-schools.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```php
$pattern = "/https?:\/\/(\S)+(\.\w{1,4})+/i"
echo preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>", $str);
```

In the pattern:

`https?` : http or https

`(\.\w{1,4})+` : TLDs like *.co* *.com* or something like *.co.uk* the maximum length of each TLD is 4 here but you can change that.